# F# interface syntax to declare a function with byref returned object (or Tuple), like Int32.TryParse

Tags: interface, f#

I'm not able to find how to declare a function in an interface so that I have a Tuple or byref result.
I want to simulate this syntax:

```ml
let executed, value = Int32.TryParse("123")
```

Let's say that I have a function with 2 input parameters and I want to know if the result is successful and in case having the result (a Record type in this case).  Kind of:

```ml
type Result = {reference:string; value:decimal}

type IExecutor =
    abstract member DoStuff: (aa:string) * (bb:string) * (result:byref<Result>) -> bool
    abstract member DoStuff: (aa:string, bb:string, result:byref<Result>) -> bool

type Executor () =
    member this.DoStuff (aa:string, bb:string, result:byref<Result>):bool =
        result <- {reference="ref"; value=0m}
        false


let executed, result = executor.DoStuff "aa" "bb"
or 
let executed, result = executor.DoStuff("aa", "bb")
```

**I'm not able to declare DoStuff in the interface.**
The second try is a copy of the *Int32.TryParse* signature I see from intellisense, why doesn't work?
What is the correct syntax for having *DoStuff* called as I want ?

Comment: I think you'll need to declare an `outref` parameter, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/byrefs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to declare an interface you use abstract members and you only apply the signature

```
type IExecutor =

    abstract member DoStuff: string*string*outref<int>->bool
```

If you want to implement the interface it goes as follows

```
type Executor() =

   interface IExecutor with

     member this.DoStuff  (a:string,b:string,result:outref<int>) : bool =
       result <- 3
       true
```

You can call it like this

```
let s = new Executor() :> IExecutor

let a,b = s.DoStuff ( "lorem" "ipsum" )
```

Having said that, if you're consuming this only from F# avoid outrefs use tuples:

```
type IExecutor =

    abstract member DoStuff: string->string->bool*int

type Executor() =

   interface IExecutor with

     member this.DoStuff  (a:string) (b:string)  : bool*int =
       true,3

let s = new Executor() :> IExecutor

let a,b = s.DoStuff "lorem" "ipsum"
```

Comment: I found the mistake and removed the names from the interface parameters but I used __byref__ (still not tested). 
Why you suggest __outref__ and not __byref__ ?

Comment: @Alex75 byref won't allow you to have return by tuples. You'd have to explicitly pass a reference parameter e.g. let mutable m = 0 s.let b = DoStuff ("lorem","ipsum",ref m).